# Editing rails migration table doesn't affect tables generated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I realized that I managed to generate a model improperly and am having trouble "rollingback" the mistake.  I was generating a model to contain questions for a parent form, writing it as follows:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table :questions do |t|
  t.integer  :legalform_id
  t.integer :question_number
  t.string :type
  t.text :the_question

  t.timestamps
end
  end
end
```

and then running `rake db:migrate` to generate the relevant tables.

The attribute `legalform_id` was to contain the id of the parent form to which the question was associated.  ...I then learned about rails and associations, realizing that what I was attempting to do was baked into the framework.  So I changed the `legalform_id` line, so that the migration table read like this:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table :questions do |t|
  t.references :legalform
  t.integer :question_number
  t.string :type
  t.text :the_question

  t.timestamps
end
  end
end
```

I entered the command `rake db:rollback` which dropped the questions table and then ran `rake db:migrate`, assuming that the change I'd made to the migration table would generate the mysql table accordingly.  Much to my surprise, the new table contained the same attributes as specified by the original migration table reading as follows:

```
mysql> show columns in questions;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| legalform_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_number | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| the_question    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What might be the cause of this?  Am I missing something?  Many thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you want. It creates the same column, while adding an index as well. `add_reference` creates the column with the name you specified, which in your case is the same as the original migration. If you run `SHOW INDEXES` on the table, you should see the newly created index as well.

Comment: Hey Brennan, thanks for the response.  I'm a little confused though.  If my changes took place, wouldn't I have a column called `legalform` and be without the column `legalform_id`?

Comment: No. Rails knows that the reference is to a foreign table. It appends `_id` to the name of the column because it knows you will be using that column to reference another table

Comment: I guess the rails development team and I share similar naming conventions then.  Many thanks!.

Comment: It's not just rails, it's a widely used database convention.

Answer (score 0):

`references` also creates the same foreign key constraints, in your case `legalform_id`, the difference between using `references` vs `legalform_id`is that when using `references` it will automatically add appropriate relationship definitions in the models and also add index for the field

Comment: Well if you create a migration & specify it to use a reference, it does.